# Как можно реализовать такую верстку?

Tags: html, css

Есть родительский flex, в нем картинки.
При ресайзе дочерние элементы скакивают на другую строку.
Можно ли как то сделать так, что бы дочерние элементы растягивались, и не оставляли пустого пространства при переносе картинок на другую строку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child">
      <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-640x400.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_a9e8c_fefaa1d2_XL-640x400.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/fon-1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/fon-2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.main {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.child {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5h91qeay/

Comment: `justify-content: space-around;` для родительского элемента? В вашем случае для `.wrapper`

Comment: это не совсем то
появляются большие промежутки между картинками, нужно что бы максимум 10px было между ними

Comment: нет, это ретина,
возможность перескакивания блоков на другую строку должна остаться
при этом пустое пространство должно заполняться, с отступами 10px

Comment: ну вот смотри к примеру, сжимай окно : https://jsfiddle.net/pg9mdc7e/3/

Comment: @MaximLensky это не то что надо, картинки в твоём примере не перестраиваются

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простыми средствами CSS это не сделать, по крайней мере на момент написания этого ответа,
Вот плагин который поможет вам это реализовать https://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/30/automatic-image-montage/
я писал примерно такой же для одного из проектов но увы его сейчас не достать

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать обычным CSS, с помощью манипуляций с `calc`. Каждому блоку флексовому мы должны посчитать максимальную ширину, к примеру, тут, на самом большом разрешении экрана в первой линии первый элемент `.post__intro.first` занимает
2/3 `max-width: calc((100% / 3) * 2 - 10px)`, также второй элемент на первой линии `.post__intro` занимает 1/3 `max-width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px);`
У второго элемента также присутствует `margin-left: 30px`, чтобы блоки вместились в одну линию мы дожны из максимальных ширин вычесть эти 30px. Я сделал так, что вычел у первого блока 10px, а у второго 20px, можно у каждого вычесть по 15px, или у одного 30px, а у другого не вычитать и всё также будет ровно.
Также для `.post__intro` я задал, что каждому `:nth-child(3n+3)` блоку 3, 6, 9, 12 и т.д. `margin-left: 0`, отступ слева нулевой.
Во всех других линиях (кроме первой) на максимальной ширине у первого блока отступ слева `0px`, а у других два по `30px`, всего получается `60px`. Если вычесть у каждого блока по `20px`, то мы вычтем эти `60px`, а мы уже задали, что у каждого блока вычитаем по `20px`. Также при сжатии блоки перестраиваются, но там логика такая же

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.container {
 max-width: 1300px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 10px;
}

.intro {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.posts__intro {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.post__intro {
 margin-top: 30px;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 30px;
 max-width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px);
}

.post__intro.first {
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 margin-left: 0;
 max-width: calc((100% / 3) * 2 - 10px);
 min-height: 470px;
}

.post__intro:nth-child(3n+3) {
 margin-left: 0;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__content {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 20px 0;
 z-index: 0;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__title {
 font-size: 34px;
 line-height: 1.25;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.post__intro__date {
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.post__intro__section {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.post__intro__section::after {
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 1px;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: black;
 transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__section::after {
 background-color: white;
}

.post__intro__section:hover::after {
 left: 100%;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__img {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__img img {
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}

.post__intro:not(.first) img {
 box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
 transition: filter .5s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.post__intro:not(.first) img:hover {
 filter: grayscale(100%)
}

.post__intro.first  .post__intro__img:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 background-color: rgba(34, 41, 47, 0.9);
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__text {
 padding: 0 100px;
 font-size: 18px;
}

.post__intro__info {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.post__intro.first .post__intro__info {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 justify-content: center;
}

.post__intro__info span:not(:last-child)::after {
 content: '·';
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.post__intro:not(.first) .post__intro__title {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.post__intro:not(.first) .post__intro__info {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
 .post__intro.first {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }

 .post__intro {
  max-width: calc(50% - 10px);
 }

 .post__intro:nth-child(3n+3) {
  margin-left: 0;
 }

 .post__intro:nth-child(2n+2) {
  margin-left: 0;
 }

 .post__intro:nth-child(2n+3) {
  margin-left: 20px;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
 .post__intro, .post__intro:nth-child(3n+3) {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
 }

 .post__intro:nth-child(2n+3) {
  margin-left: 0;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 550px) {

 .post__intro.first .post__intro__text {
  padding: 0 50px;
 }

 .post__intro.first .post__intro__title {
  line-height: 1.125;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 300px) {

 .post__intro.first .post__intro__title {
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 0;
 }

 .post__intro.first .post__intro__text {
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="posts__intro">

   <div class="post__intro first">
    <div class="post__intro__img">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/750/750" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
     <div class="post__intro__title">
      Zero BS CRM 3.0 Improves UI, Changes Database Structure, and Becomes More Extendable
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__info">
      <span class="post__intro__date">
       7 декабря, 2019
      </span>
      <span class="post__intro__section">
       Новости
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__text">
      The team behind Zero BS CRM launched version 3.0 of their WordPress plugin today. This is the first major release … 
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
   </div> <!-- .post__intro.first -->

   <div class="post__intro">
    <div class="post__intro__img">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/750/750" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
     <div class="post__intro__title">
      Gutenberg: One Year Later
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__info">
      <span class="post__intro__date">
       7 декабря, 2019
      </span>
      <span class="post__intro__section">
       Новости
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__text">
      As we quickly head into the final weeks of 2019, we also pass the first anniversary of WordPress 5.0 and, … 
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
   </div> <!-- .post__intro -->

   <div class="post__intro">
    <div class="post__intro__img">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/750/750" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
     <div class="post__intro__title">
      Gutenberg: One Year Later
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__info">
      <span class="post__intro__date">
       7 декабря, 2019
      </span>
      <span class="post__intro__section">
       Новости
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__text">
      As we quickly head into the final weeks of 2019, we also pass the first anniversary of WordPress 5.0 and, … 
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
   </div> <!-- .post__intro -->

   <div class="post__intro">
    <div class="post__intro__img">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/750/750" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
     <div class="post__intro__title">
      Gutenberg: One Year Later
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__info">
      <span class="post__intro__date">
       7 декабря, 2019
      </span>
      <span class="post__intro__section">
       Новости
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__text">
      As we quickly head into the final weeks of 2019, we also pass the first anniversary of WordPress 5.0 and, … 
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
   </div> <!-- .post__intro -->

   <div class="post__intro">
    <div class="post__intro__img">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/750/750" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
     <div class="post__intro__title">
      Gutenberg: One Year Later
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__info">
      <span class="post__intro__date">
       7 декабря, 2019
      </span>
      <span class="post__intro__section">
       Новости
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__text">
      As we quickly head into the final weeks of 2019, we also pass the first anniversary of WordPress 5.0 and, … 
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
   </div> <!-- .post__intro -->

   <div class="post__intro">
    <div class="post__intro__img">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/750/750" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
     <div class="post__intro__title">
      Gutenberg: One Year Later
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__info">
      <span class="post__intro__date">
       7 декабря, 2019
      </span>
      <span class="post__intro__section">
       Новости
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__text">
      As we quickly head into the final weeks of 2019, we also pass the first anniversary of WordPress 5.0 and, … 
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
   </div> <!-- .post__intro -->

   <div class="post__intro">
    <div class="post__intro__img">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/750/750" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
     <div class="post__intro__title">
      Gutenberg: One Year Later
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__info">
      <span class="post__intro__date">
       7 декабря, 2019
      </span>
      <span class="post__intro__section">
       Новости
      </span>
     </div>
     <div class="post__intro__text">
      As we quickly head into the final weeks of 2019, we also pass the first anniversary of WordPress 5.0 and, … 
     </div>
    </div> <!-- .post__intro__content -->
   </div> <!-- .post__intro -->

  </div> <!-- .posts__intro -->

 </div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- .intro -->
```