# Две колонки без разделения элемента | убрать расстояние между колонками | количество колонок такое, чтобы экран был заполнен по ширине

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такой код.
1) Как сделать, чтобы элемент №3 не ломался на 2 части? [Решение уже получено в ответе.]
**2) Как убрать расстояние между колонками? То есть чтобы вторая колонка примыкала к элементу №2.**
3) Как сделать так, чтобы количество колонок такого формата (у них нужное выравнивание - по левой стороне) высчитывалось браузером автоматически исходя из ширины экрана?

Без использования `max-height`, потому что количество элементов и их размер будут меняться. Из-за этого использование двух контейнеров для колонок тоже не подходит.

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  column-count: 2
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<div class="item" style="height:100px;width:80px">1</div>
<div class="item" style="height:80px;width:100px">2</div>
<div class="item" style="height:60px;width:60px">3</div>
<div class="item" style="height:100px;width:100px">4</div>
<div class="item" style="height:120px;width:120px">5</div>
```

Comment: А вы именно так хотите, не хотите использовать flex и grid? С ними всё намного проще.

Comment: Хочу, но чтобы было именно такое выравнивание. С flex и grid почему-то не получается. Они по строкам выравнивают. А нужно только колонки без использования точной высоты `body`, так как количество и размер элементов может меняться.

Comment: я плохо понимаю, что вы хотите, если вы приложите несколько визуальных примеров, я смогу понять, что вы хотите сделать. Возможно, вам это может помочь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1065196/331312 и ещё https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1059852/331312

Answer (score 3):

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  column-count: 2
}

.item {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  /* Firefox */
  break-inside: avoid;
  /* IE 10+ */
  border: 1px solid #000
}

Можно так, но чтобы убрать important нужно вычистить ширину из html
```

```html
<div class="item" style="height:100px;width:80px">1</div>
<div class="item" style="height:80px;width:100px">2</div>
<div class="item" style="height:60px;width:60px">3</div>
<div class="item" style="height:100px;width:100px">4</div>
<div class="item" style="height:120px;width:120px">5</div>
```

Comment: А чего у они вдруг стали одной ширины?

Comment: width: 100% !important;

Comment: Важно, чтобы ширина оставалась разной. И как менять расстояние между колонками?

Comment: .item {  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  /* Firefox */
  break-inside: avoid;
  /* IE 10+ */
}

Comment: Вот, теперь готово )

Comment: А как ещё убрать расстояние между колонками? То есть чтобы вторая колонка примыкала к элементу №2.

Comment: Добавлен третий подвопрос.

Comment: `break-inside` поддерживается во всех браузерах. `page-break-inside` и `webkit` вроде бы вообще не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Вы такое хотите?

```css
.flex__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<div class="flex__wrapper">
  <div class="item" style="height:100px;width:80px">1</div>
  <div class="item" style="height:80px;width:100px">2</div>
  <div class="item" style="height:60px;width:60px">3</div>
  <div class="item" style="height:100px;width:100px">4</div>
  <div class="item" style="height:120px;width:120px">5</div>
  <div class="item" style="height:100px;width:80px">1</div>
  <div class="item" style="height:80px;width:100px">2</div>
  <div class="item" style="height:60px;width:60px">3</div>
  <div class="item" style="height:100px;width:100px">4</div>
  <div class="item" style="height:120px;width:120px">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, такое, но без использования `max-height` (его уже пробовал), потому что размер и количество элементов будут меняться. То есть нужно не частное, а общее решение.

Comment: @oleedd ну тогда гриды

Comment: Хорошо, но у меня с ними не получилось (выравнивает по ячейкам, а не по колонкам), хотя в них там много всего.

Comment: @oleedd А почему вас не устраивает `max-height`? Вы же всё-таки как-то должны ограничивать высоту блока, а в следующую колонку элементы будут сами переходить

Comment: Просто общая высота всех элементов будет каждый раз разной. Это как вводишь данные, а оно преобразуется в колонки. Количество колонок нужно такое, которое влазит в экран (чтобы была возможность всё распечатать, максимально используя свободное место). `inline-block` делает такой эффект, но выравнивает по ячейкам, а не по колонкам.

Comment: @oleedd а так вам подойдёт?

Comment: Это интересный вариант, но тоже не подходит. Все элементы точно в экран не влезут (они значительно больше). То есть нужно такое же распределение, как при `column-count`, для минимального количества листов при печати. А вообще, очень хотелось отрегулировать ширину колонки при `column-count` по содержимому, то есть чтобы колонки могли быть разной ширины. Вроде бы элементарно, а это не предусмотрели.

Comment: @oleedd возможно вам это ещё сможет помочь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/593650/331312

Comment: Не вижу в коде этого ответа ничего нового. В других вопросах везде одинаковая ширина, а у меня разная.